# Better way to do nested subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a certain query using SQL Server that works but is probably not the best way to do it. I have a series of nested subqueries, but I can't figure out the right joins to make it work. I have simple tables like this:

- Table `UG` links users and groups - two int columns: `uid` and `groupid`
- Table `RG` links roles and groups - two int columns: `roleid` and `groupid`
- Table `RU` links roles and users - two int columns: `roleid` and `uid`

The goal is to find all `ug` entries where the `groupid` is NOT in the `roleid` specified, but only for users IN this particular role. Like exceptions from a pre-defined role.

This here

```
select *
from ug 
where ug.uid in (select uid from ru where ru.roleid = 77)
  and ug.groupid not in (select groupid from rg where rg.roleid = 77)
```

is for roleid 77 and works. But is this a "bad" way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to check multiple values you can use IN (Subquery) as IN is used to filer a column for a certain list. And If you want to check the availability of the  value in a certain table, you got for EXISTS.  Since you want to retrieve the UG.* for roleid = 77 it is good to use Exists. but if you need to check availability for Multiple roleIds you can probably use IN. 
Performance perspective EXISTS is more better than IN as Exists returns true for the first occurrence. We Use Exists in Condition checks commonly.   Hope this explanation is clear to you @atomz4peace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is fine.  However, I strongly discourage using `not in` with a subquery, because it does not work intuitively if the subquery returns *any* `NULL` values.

For consistency, I also generally use `exists` instead of `in` (although there are no semantic issues).  That suggests:

```
select *
from ug 
where exists (select 1 from ru where ug.uid = ru.uid and ru.roleid = 77) and
     not exists (select 1 from rg where ug.groupid = rg.groupid and rg.roleid = 77);
```

Comment: This one was accurate. 

But then I realized I didn't consider all options in my question. Turns out you might choose more than one roleid. In those cases, my initial thought was not right at all. If roleid is >0, then you get ALL Groups, even if the user does not have the role that gives the groups. If i'm in 1 role but the not exists counts all roles.

Comment: @atomz4peace . . . Perhaps you should ask a new question with a clear description of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

This would be faster when you have a lot of results in your subqueries

```
SELECT ug.*
FROM ug
INNER JOIN ru ON ug.uig = ru.uid AND ru.roleid = 77
INNER JOIN rg ON ug.groupid = rg.groupid AND rg.roleid <> 77
```

Comment: Possibly, but it could introduce double counting issues if joins are not 1:1

Comment: This will return duplicate data if the mapping is not 1:1.  (Check 1:M)

Comment: This one was on the right track but not entirely accurate. For some reason it returned a groupid from ug that was in role 77.

Answer (score 0):

So now knowing more about my own problem, I used both ideas from above to get a new solution. We are now assuming that the roleid can be a single role OR any roleid at all, even > 0, or all roles. In my testing, it seems like a left join of a new subtable where roleid is null does the trick to just give the left side of the classic join venn diagram.

This gives a more defined link so that we only get the groups for the user from JUST the roles they are part of. It seems like this works no matter which roleid. Still testing since that last where clause is really odd-looking, but needed to limit the scope to just the people in the selected roles. Otherwise we return ALL people, even those not in the selected role.

Sorry I didn't know the full question, but thank you for the answers and direction.

```
select * from ug 
left join (
select ru.uid, ru.roleid, rg.groupid from ru inner join rg ru.roleid = rg.roleid
    and ru.roleid > 0 (or anything really)
) as rug on rug.uid = ug.uid and rug.groupid = ug.groupid
where roleid is null
and ug.uid in (select uid from ru where ru.roleid  > 0) (same as above roleid)
```